# CssClass not Changing in Asp.net Website

Tags: asp.net, webforms, css

I am using a MasterPage for my website, with various tabs that are placed in the the header (of the MasterPage).  The code for the tabs looks like (written in C#):

```
<ul id="tabMenu">                 
    <li><asp:HyperLink ID="homeLink" runat="server" onclick="homeButton_Click()" 
         NavigateUrl="~/Default.aspx">Home</asp:HyperLink></li>
</ul>
```

This of course is a single tab, but the rest are very similar.  Clicking this link triggers the homeButton_Click() in the code behind, which looks like:

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    homeLink.CssClass.Insert(0, "activeTab");
}
```

The only difference in the current CSS class to the intended one (activeTab) is the change of the background-image.  Currently when I click on this tab the CSS class does not change, and the color stays the same.

Any suggestions as to what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: you should do: homeLink.CssClass = "activeTab"; not the insert.

Comment: can you post the HTML source (from the browser) and CSS for this please

Comment: @DavidePiras I think you have the *answer*.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried setting the css class like this instead:

```
homeLink.CssClass = "activeTab";
```

Answer (score 1):

You can assign cssclass using below code

```
homeLink.Attributes.Add("class", "abc");
```